# Change the string of button in odoo eCommerce website

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-view, odoo-website

[I want to change string on Add to Cart button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmkIE.png)

I want to change the label string on Add to Cart button. In attached image
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Xpath` to locate and replace it like this:

```
<xpath expr="//a[@id='add_to_cart']" position="replace">

    <a id="add_to_cart" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg mt8 js_check_product a-submit" href="#">Your custom text</a>

</xpath>
```